# About the example Azure Storage Blob CRUD with Apim and MSI

Tags: azure-api-management

I found this example on Apim repo: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Authenticate%20using%20Managed%20Identity%20to%20access%20Storage%20Account.xml
Could someone please explain a better examples with CRUD and Msi (deep dive policies) ? What if if I need handle a file of different type ( not json object) ? What about to send this file to blob ? I`m trying to get a  file from a S3 (via get API) and write this to an blob storage.
I can Get data from S3 using send request, otherwise when I try sent that to Blob storage is generated an error because the type of file isn't a pure json object:

```
`<send-request mode="new" timeout="20" response-variable-name="blobdata2" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>https://{{storage}}.blob.core.windows.net/container</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="x-ms-version" exists-action="override">
            <value>2019-07-07</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="x-ms-blob-type" exists-action="override">
            <value>BlockBlob</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="x-ms-type" exists-action="override">
            <value>file</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@($"{((IResponse)context.Variables["blobdata"]).Body.As<JObject>() }")</setbody>
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://storage.azure.com" />
    </send-request>`
```

Here I`m trying send "**blobdata**" because is the variable that contains the file from the first Send-Request ( not presented here). The error I received is following:

```
"Expression evaluation failed. The message body is not a valid JSON. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: P. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.AsJObject(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.As[T](Boolean preserveContent)", "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: P. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

Comment: Please check the value of variable 'blobdata'. You can do this in the trace

Comment: @MarkusMeyer with Send request policy isn't possible check this variable, the trace just report that value was read to post use:

Comment: Yes, this will be changed by MS. You have to add custom tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Trace or assign a variable with the response body. The variable value is visible in the trace.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer this is the challenge , because in a SendRequest policy the variable already exist (blobdata), the  challenge is to read that or trace because it's a file (doesn't have a format like json), in this case I know its a xlsx, but  we can't see that on trace..

Comment: Did you try a few options here?
@($"{((IResponse)context.Variables["blobdata"]).Body.As<JObject>() }")
@($"{((IResponse)context.Variables["blobdata"]).Body.As<string>() }")

Comment: Yes, I get the error presented.